# I have a problem in a div element position

Tags: css, position, css-position

Im trying to position the div element in the center responsively but the top-left corner act as I want (it goes to center instead of the whole div) what should I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <input class="click-button" type="button" name="button" value="Click" onclick="clearWrite()"></button>
  <p id="text"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.7); }

.container {
  background-color: white;
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using translate(-50%,-50%) it would shift in Y and X axis to 50%  of its height and width.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.7);
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /** add this **/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <input class="click-button" type="button" name="button" value="Click" onclick="clearWrite()">
  <p id="text"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```